# NER combining BIO tokens to form original compound word

Tags: python, named-entity-recognition

Any way to combine the BIO tokens into compound words.
I implemented this method to form words from BIO schema but this does not work well for words with punctuations. For eg: S.E.C using the below function will join it as S . E . C

```
def collapse(ner_result):
    # List with the result
    collapsed_result = []


    current_entity_tokens = []
    current_entity = None

    # Iterate over the tagged tokens
    for token, tag in ner_result:

        if tag.startswith("B-"):
            # ... if we have a previous entity in the buffer, store it in the result list
            if current_entity is not None:
                collapsed_result.append([" ".join(current_entity_tokens), current_entity])

            current_entity = tag[2:]
            # The new entity has so far only one token
            current_entity_tokens = [token]

        # If the entity continues ...
        elif current_entity_tokens!= None and tag == "I-" + str(current_entity):
            # Just add the token buffer
            current_entity_tokens.append(token)
        else:
            collapsed_result.append([" ".join(current_entity_tokens), current_entity])
            collapsed_result.append([token,tag[2:]])

            current_entity_tokens = []
            current_entity = None

            pass

    # The last entity is still in the buffer, so add it to the result
    # ... but only if there were some entity at all
    if current_entity is not None:
        collapsed_result.append([" ".join(current_entity_tokens), current_entity])
        collapsed_result = sorted(collapsed_result)
        collapsed_result = list(k for k,_ in itertools.groupby(collapsed_result))


    return collapsed_result
```

Another method:-

I tried to detokenize using TreebankWordDetokenizer but it still did not form the original sentence. For eg: Orig: sentence -> `parties. \n \n IN WITNESS WHEREOF, the parties hereto`
tokenized and detokenized sentence -> `parties . IN WITNESS WHEREOF, the parties hereto`

Another example: Orig: sentence -> `Group’s employment, Group shall be`
tokenized and detokenized sentence -> `Group ’ s employment, Group shall be`

Note that period and newlines are stripped using the TreebankWordDetokenizer.

Any workaround to form compound words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A really small fix should do the job:

```
def join_tokens(tokens):
    res = ''
    if tokens:
        res = tokens[0]
        for token in tokens[1:]:
            if not (token.isalpha() and res[-1].isalpha()):
                res += token  # punctuation
            else:
                res += ' ' + token  # regular word
    return res

def collapse(ner_result):
    # List with the result
    collapsed_result = []


    current_entity_tokens = []
    current_entity = None

    # Iterate over the tagged tokens
    for token, tag in ner_result:

        if tag.startswith("B-"):
            # ... if we have a previous entity in the buffer, store it in the result list
            if current_entity is not None:
                collapsed_result.append([join_tokens(current_entity_tokens), current_entity])

            current_entity = tag[2:]
            # The new entity has so far only one token
            current_entity_tokens = [token]

        # If the entity continues ...
        elif current_entity_tokens!= None and tag == "I-" + str(current_entity):
            # Just add the token buffer
            current_entity_tokens.append(token)
        else:
            collapsed_result.append([join_tokens(current_entity_tokens), current_entity])
            collapsed_result.append([token,tag[2:]])

            current_entity_tokens = []
            current_entity = None

            pass

    # The last entity is still in the buffer, so add it to the result
    # ... but only if there were some entity at all
    if current_entity is not None:
        collapsed_result.append([join_tokens(current_entity_tokens), current_entity])
        collapsed_result = sorted(collapsed_result)
        collapsed_result = list(k for k, _ in itertools.groupby(collapsed_result))

    return collapsed_result
```

#### Update

This will solve most of the cases, but as can be seen in comments below there always be outliers. So the complete solution is to track the identity of the word that created certain token. Thus

```
text="U.S. Securities and Exchange Commission"
lut = [(token, ix) for ix, word in enumerate(text.split()) for token in tokenize(w)]  

# lut = [("U",0), (".",0), ("S",0), (".",0), ("Securities",1), ("and",2), ("Exchange",3), ("Commision",4)]
```

Now, given token index you can know exact word it came from, and simply concatenate tokens that belong to the same word, while adding space when a token belongs to a different word. So the NER result would be something like:

```
[["U","B-ORG", 0], [".","I-ORG", 0], ["S", "I-ORG", 0], [".","I-ORG", 0], ['Securities', 'I-ORG', 1], ['and', 'I-ORG', 2], ['Exchange', 'I-ORG',3], ['Commission', 'I-ORG', 4]]
```

Comment: It worked for most cases. But an outlier: The tags for the sentence "U.S. Securities and Exchange Commission" are ['U.S.', 'B-ORG']
['Securities', 'I-ORG']
['and', 'I-ORG']
['Exchange', 'I-ORG']
['Commission', 'I-ORG']

And when run the collapse command changed the sentence into: "U.S.Securities and Exchange Commission"

Comment: The other option is to split by words, and then tokenize each word separately. This will help you to create an index of correspondence between each token and the original word. And then you will be able to rebuild original words from tokens.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Sorry, I did not follow that.

Comment: "U.S. Securities and Exchange Commission" will become  ["U.S.",  "Securities", "and",  "Exchange", "Commission"]. Then you tokenize it, and create LUT token to word index. {"U":0, ".":0, "S":0, ".":0, "Securities":1, "and":2, "Exchange":3, "Commision":4]. Then when you recreate original words, you use those indices. If it is the same, you join as is, if it is different you add " " between the tokens.

Comment: That could be a good workaround. But, I could also create LUT for each word: {"U.S.":0, "Securities":1, "and":2, "Exchange":3, "Commision":4}. And when recreating,  ['U.S.', 'B-ORG'] ['Securities', 'I-ORG'] ['and', 'I-ORG'] ['Exchange', 'I-ORG'] ['Commission', 'I-ORG'], join words using " " if every word found in LUT. Does that work?

Comment: Yes, this is the general idea. It depends on tokenizer. In my case it splits the words if they have punctuation marks inside, so "U.S." will become 4 tokens: ["U", ".", "S", "."] and you can't mix up first and second dots.

Comment: That's true. I did not think about that scenario. This surely solves the problem of retaining the original word while combing the BIO schema tags. Thank you.

You could add that to the answer so that I can mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: I wasn't clear enough, the index is not a dictionary, it is a list of all tokens and the word that created them :  [ ("U":0), (".":0), ("S":0), (".":0), ("Securities":1), ("and":2), ("Exchange":3), ("Commision":4)]